# How to delete an user account with terminal

Tags: command-line, useradd

I created a new account on my Linux OS, using the `useradd` command, now I want to delete the account created, I'm trying to use the `userdel` command to delete that account and I get the following error:

> userdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\

I don't understand what that error means.

The syntax I used to delete the account was: `userdel -r "accountname"` , I also used `"accountname" userdel` but I didn't work.

Can someone help me delete this account using the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably because you do not use the `userdel` command as superuser (root) or other privileged user. Try:

```
sudo userdel accountname
```

As stated in several comments it is also possible to remove the homedirectory configured while removing the useraccount using:

```
sudo userdel -r accountname
```

Comment: I just tried `sudo userdel accountname` and it didn't give me an errors but when I list my home directory the user still appears, If i did `rm -r accountname` on the home directory would that get rid of the account when I start the machine?

Comment: Useraccounts and homedirectories are seperate things. Use `getent passwd accountname` (accountname is optional) to lookup accounts and use `ls /home` to get a list of home directories. If you want to remove a useraccount _and_ to remove the attached homedirectory use `sudo userdel -r accountname`. If you want to keep the homedirectory, omit the `-r` flag.

Comment: Using `ls -l /home` you can normally see the ownername and groupname on the directories for an existing user.  If the homedirectory still exists but the useraccount is removed, you will see numeric value(s) instead, indicating that a user can not be looked up.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the user account at login with the following command `sudo userdel -r accountname` but it didn't get rid of the account name on the home directory.

Comment: Also I do see the binary digits when  I do `ls -l`

Comment: If the directory (which happens to be a homedirectory for a user) still exists in `/home/` and you want to get rid of it, remove the directory as superuser using `sudo rm -rf /home/useraccount`. The reason that you see something like `drwxr-xr-x 4 1003 1003 ... useraccount` when running `ls -l /home` is that the useraccount is removed so 1003 can not be translated (looked up) to a username anymore but the directory with the name of the removed useraccount exists. It is just a directory, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thank your very much for your time and excellent explanations. `rm -rf` solve my question.

Comment: Usually `userdel` has an option (`-r`) for removing the user's files as well, including their mail-file.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I mentioned that in my first comment :-), changed the answer to have it more in sight.

Comment: I see it now - in your *second* comment.  But to improve the answer, you should factor in most of the followup comments in revisions to the answer (it keeps the discussion from trailing off, and comments can be lost).

Answer (score 0):

A more modern way to do this is with the `deluser` command:

- `sudo deluser --remove-all-files $USER_TO_DELETE`

See [the manual page](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man8/deluser.8.html) for details.